# NVARCHAR2 select where variable='€'

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, nvarchar

I have to use an old charset WE8ISO8859P1 (it a working environment, not sure why but I cannot change this) so I had to change my variable to NVARCHAR2.
Only problem when I try to filter based on the eur symbol € it will not return anything, while before the filter was working in my select but using varchar2 it will display as ¿

I want to be able to insert the € in my oracle db and be able to do a

```
select * from mytable where myvariable='€';
```

Is that even possible without changing the charset?

Comment: Are you saying it won't filter on that value, or it displays that value incorrectly? What does `dump(myvariable, 1016)` say was actually inserted? For insert and query you can prefix the [string literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA) with `n` to make it national character set - so `myvariable=n'€';` - but for display your client settings need to be right too.

Comment: @AlexPoole actually the solution with n is good for me. The value was not filtered...

Comment: ok i understand it now... I used sql developer to insert my € and in the log I can see it actually insert with the n, so it make sense that it need the n in the where in select mode too.

Comment: @AlexPoole if you write your answer as answer both here and in the question I made today I can accept them.